# Race condition in pessimistic locking example of rails documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, race-condition

I'm looking at the following example of the [Rails documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html):

```
account = Account.first
account.with_lock do
  # This block is called within a transaction,
  # account is already locked.
  account.balance -= 100
  account.save!
end
```

My understanding is that the `first` method returns a record straight from the database, rather than a relation (similar to `find`). Now suppose `balance = 200` and we have two concurrent requests, where both of them execute `account = Account.first` before they reach the `with_lock` block. Both requests now have `200` in memory.

Then, one request locks the record and modifies `balance` to 100. But when it unlocks the record, the second request will not read `balance` again, but it will have the old value of `200`, so we'll still end up with race condition in this case. So my question is, shouldn't `account = Account.first` also be wrapped in `with_lock` block to truly avoid race condition?

Comment: From the docs for [`with_lock`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-with_lock): _"Wraps the passed block in a transaction, **reloading the object** with a lock before yielding."_ (emphasis mine)

Comment: Ah, I missed that, but it explains that the docs example is race condition safe! Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with_lock` reloads the object before yielding to the block, from the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-with_lock):

> Wraps the passed block in a transaction, reloading the object with a lock before yielding.

The `with_lock` example from the docs is (almost) equivalent to:

```
account = Account.first
account.transaction do
  account.reload(lock: true)
  account.balance -= 100
  account.save!
end
```

The [`reload`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) call ensures that the object's attributes get updated from the database.